# Security of javascript image upload and view

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload

As a js-firsttimer, wanna ask if script below is proper (security), considering that filetype is detected and processed via php.

http://jsfiddle.net/kwCks/2/

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

$("#file").change(function(e) {
var file, img, size;


if ((file = this.files[0])) {

    if(file.size < "5100000"){
        size = "good";
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            if((this.height/(this.width / 64)) < "200"){
                if(size == "good"){
                    //alert("ok to upload");
                $("#blah").attr("src", img.src);
                }
            }else{ alert("File is too big (dimensions)");}
        };
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
    } else {
        size = "big";
        alert("File is too big, use 5MB or smaller");
    }


}

});
```

EDIT PHP PART

```
if(isset($_POST["titletext"])){


echo $_POST["titletext"];
if (!$_FILES["avafile"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["avafile"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["avafile"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["avafile"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["avafile"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["avafile"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . md5($_FILES["avafile"]["name"]));
    echo '<img class="img-rounded" style="width: 64px;" src="./upload/'.$_FILES["avafile"]["name"].'">';
}
```

}

Also wanna now if there's a way to detect script/text uploaded as image and use some "striptags" for it.

Images are being uploaded with md5(something) name.

Comment: Most of the security considerations for the upload would be on the serverside - for instance, in PHP code. (One example might be accidentally allowing "serverinfect.php" to be uploaded, and accidentally putting it in a runnable wwwroot location) Do you have any PHP code to post?

Comment: I'm quite sure that if ((file = this.files[0])) is always true since x = true is true and x = false is true. Please correct me if I'm wrong in this context. I.e. assigning any value to a variable is always true.

Comment: @Katana314 Validation should be done both Client side and Server side. I'd say that file extension is included in that, I wouldn't want an .exe or .bat be running around even if it's get validated on the server. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: @Jonast92 That's true, although I would think of code like that as 'validation', rather than 'security', to helpfully prevent users from doing something dumb, without giving them a straight PHP error. If you're trying to prevent a mastermind hacker from breaking your server or fooling your other users, he'll never run your JavaScript - he'll be running his own customized series of HTTP requests to try to find holes. He doesn't have to follow any of your JS script's rules.

Comment: Thanks for comments! As you in fiddle, there's {accept="image/*"} in the form, so only images allowed.
Also, how could i "unload" image? sometimes it gets through even if not in canvas =(

Comment: Added not-done php part, debug mostly right now

Comment: @Katana314 I'm talking about both categories, I am aware that JavaScript walls won't do anything for a mastermind hacker but you can prevent the casual users from doing something wrong that you didn't think about before (or if you did a mistake on the server) and at best you could be preventing bots from uploading malicious files into your server and in some cases prevent the medium hackers from achieving what they want. Whatever the conclusion is, do validation on both sides.

Comment: @Jonast92 Yup! That's all stuff I agree with. I guess the only disconnect was on the terms "security" vs "validation" but I guess that hardly matters.

Comment: Updated fiddle to unload file in case of error http://jsfiddle.net/kwCks/4/